# Change / Switch Development FTP Server for Project - PhpStorm

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

I created project from existing files by FTP.

But now I want to change my FTP, I added new connection and assigned as default, etc.

But in `Tools- > Deployment` only old FTP host, right-click on project - upload / download only from/to old host.

How to change my new FTP deployment for this project? Without creating new one project? Just by adding new connection and switch?

Comment: Your new deployment entry must be incomplete / not all settings were set .. because all entries that are applicable to current project should be listed in "Deployment" menu. Therefore: 1) Please ensure that you have no warnings on ALL tabs of your new Deployment entry 2) If you think that all is good there -- post screenshots with what you have got. **P.S.** Just in case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne thank you, you were right, one thing were missing without squawking and I didnt know